# IE9 CSS text-align not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I have a problem with a CSS on IE9 - text on a banner here http://bit.ly/1pbjEDE should be left aligned but it's centered (that's a default value). Weird enough when I use Dev Mode to emulate IE9.0 it works fine - but it's broken on an older machines and on browserstack.com.

CSS:

```
.desc-wrapper {text-align: left; max-width:450px; padding-top:0px; padding-left:40px; margin-right:40%; margin-left:auto;}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

ie9 is getting a different stylesheet and it has text-align:center on .desc-wrapper.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJk0u.jpg - the "if gte IE 9" is a [conditional comment](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).